# How can I shorten the output of lines that have been written to a text file

Tags: python, text

I am writing a script to ssh to all the switches I've got, run a command, then take the output and send it to the text file. However the output I'm getting needs to be filtered down to just a few useful things. I only need to know the interface and the vlan it's on. I wrote another script to take the text file made by the first one to do the text filtering but It's not quite enough. I'll post the code to both so that you can understand the full context

```py
f = open("vlancheck.txt", "a+")
hostname = "host here"
port = 22
username = getpass.getpass(prompt="Username: ") #used for hiding input
password = getpass.getpass()
command = "show interface status | e disabled"
string = " "

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient() #starts ssh client
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) #generates ssh key for all unknown hosts
ssh.connect(hostname, port=port, username=username, password=password) # logs in with the credentials stored in variables


stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command) #manages input,output, and error data generated by the command sent
output = stdout.readlines() #reads the output as a list
print("\n".join(output))
f.write(hostname)
f.writelines(output) # writes the output as a list
f.close()
```

```py
open("truncated.txt" , "w+").writelines([line for line in open("vlancheck.txt") if "Gi" in line])
```

I am working with cisco switches and this is the output I get with my filter script:

`Gi1/0/6                      connected    708        a-full  a-100 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi1/0/9                      connected    708        a-full  a-100 10/100/1000BaseTX`

This is good, but I want to shorten it to be something like:

`Gi1/0/6                      connected    708
Gi1/0/9                      connected    708`

Answer (score 0):

So assuming I understand your question correctly and the code you've provided...your output `Gi1/0/6                      connected    708        a-full  a-100 10/100/1000BaseTX` is displayed by this line: `print("\n".join(output))`

Assuming your output variable is a list, I have created a sample below:

```
output = ['Gi1/0/6','connected','708', 'a-full','a-100','10/100/1000BaseTX']
print('    '.join(output[0:3]))
```

returns:

```
Gi1/0/6     connected     708
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this output `Gi1/0/9 connected 70`

Use regix `re.sub()`

This is how you use it.

```
print re.sub(' +', ' ',output)
```

It will eliminate duplicate spaces in the variable that you use

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helping me out. I did actually figure it out myself. I'll post what I did. It's probably not the best but it definitely works!

```
with open("hosts.txt") as l:
    line = l.readline()
    print(line)
    while line is not None:
        for host in line:
            host = "".join(line)
            host = host.strip('\n')
            #print(host)
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient() #starts ssh client
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) #generates ssh key for all unknown hosts
            ssh.connect(host, port=port, username=username, password=password) # logs in with the credentials stored in variables
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command) #manages input,output, and error data generated by the command sent
            output = stdout.readlines() #reads the output as a list
            #print("\n".join(output))
            f.write(host + "\n")
            for i in output:
                if i.startswith("Gi"):
                    f.writelines(i[0:46] + "\n") # writes the output as a list
            line = l.readline()
```